# Parse Dashboard not working

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, dashboard, parse-server

I manually created a mongDB and deployed this [parse server example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) example to heroku
now I want use Parse dashboard for this using

```
parse-dashboard --appId yourAppId --masterKey yourMasterKey --serverURL "https://example.com/parse" --appName optionalName
```

From where can I obtain the parameters mentioned above like appId,masterKey,serverUrl and appName

After running this with default appId, masterKey and appName but heroku  serverURL its runs dashboard, but on dashboard page it
says **"Server not reachable: unable to connect to server"**

From where can I obtain the parameters mentioned above like appId,masterKey,serverUrl and appName

Why is the server unreachable??

Comment: Where did you create MongoDB? Is it on your local machine or on the Heroku?

Comment: @NidhinDavid
I created it on mLab

Comment: Have you tried this: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-the-parse-server-dashboard/

Comment: I tried similar steps but actual issue is 
"from where I 'll get appId and masterKey??? "

Comment: Are you migrating an existing app? If not then both of them can be any arbitrary value assigned by you. If you are migrating from existing parse then you can find them inside that parse dashboard

Comment: I installed Parse server locally in which I provided appId and masterKey, it is working fine for Parse Dashboard but 
I installing it on heroku I don't know where to set appId and masterKey

Comment: Its  new one, not migrating
but random keys are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First you must** run the parse-server-example **by setting** appId and masterKey
Either you can edit the index.js file(https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example/blob/master/index.js) and hard code the value or you can set it by using heroku env variables. read this page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

You can set it as

```
 heroku config:set APP_ID=yourAppId
 heroku config:set MASTER_KEY=yourMasterKey
 heroku config:set MONGODB_URI=yourMongoUriformMlab
 heroku config:set SERVER_URL=https://enigmatic-wave-36871.herokuapp.com/parse
```

Please refer this for more detailed info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku

It **can be any value** that you like.

Next you have edit the `parse-dashboard-config.json` in 'parse-dashboard' and provide the `appId` and `MasterKey` **that you gave earlier in the parse-server-example** and save it and start it, you can refer this link:http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-the-parse-server-dashboard/

After editing, the `parse-dashboard-config.json` should contain:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": "https://enigmatic-wave-36871.herokuapp.com/parse",
      "appId": "The appid that you gave for the parse-server-example",
      "masterKey": "The master key that you gave for parse-server-example",
      "appName": "enginamatic-wave anything you like"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal Then try hard-coding them in the index.js file

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal If you cannot set env variables then how do you set mongo uri to mLab?

Comment: I followed a tutorial
there was nothing like rocket science in it'

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal App id and Master key are an arbitrary value that you can set. You must use those value in your 'client' app to connect to it. You can give them as whatever you want

Comment: ok
in serverULR  I 'm writing "https://enigmatic-wave-36871.herokuapp.com"
is it the correct syntex?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal "enigmatic-wave-36871.herokuapp.com/parse" is the correct url

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal I 'am now confused, are you talking about parse-server or parse-dashboard?

Comment: I 'talking about parse dashboard now
I deployed "parse serve example" at heroku and I want to access it from parse dashborad
with "/parse" it say "Server not reachable: unauthorized"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109045/discussion-between-nidhin-david-and-muhammad-faisal-iqbal).

Comment: last thing which solve the issue:
I manually put appId, masterKey and ServerURL in index.json, and than push my parse server example again. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this, it worked for me

```
parse-dashboard --appId yourAppId --masterKey yourMasterKey --serverURL https://example.com/parse --appName optionalName
```

The key here is that the server URL needs to be taken *out* of the double quotes.

Comment: Initally I also faced the same problem but when I tried entering the url without double quotation mark it connected to my parse dashboard

Comment: Awesome! I went ahead and edited that into your answer for clarity. Go ahead and double check to make sure that I got it right.

Answer (score 1):

In your Heroku account, go into the app that you are working on. Now, go into Settings and click on reveal config vars. Copy the keys into their respective places in the terminal code. Make sure to put the server irk in quotes as you have in your example. The serverURL should be "yourAppName.heroku.com/parse".

Comment: But there is no appId, masterKey or serverURL in config vars

Comment: Are you migrating an old app or starting a new one?

Comment: starting a new one

Comment: and is it necessary to add "/parse" after my serverURL???
with "/parse" it say unauthorized at dashboard
and without "/parse" it say "unable to connect to server"

Comment: I just realized I answered twice to this question...sorry about that. You should have /parse at the end

Answer (score 0):

It appears that something went wrong when you configured the server. Delete the app from Heroku and follow [this](https://youtu.be/mup6Da41IjQ) tutorial (instead of using Rob's server example, use the Parse server example).

Comment: He wants to connect parse-dashboard with his parse-server-example. The video is teaching how to create a parse app using heroku dashboard and connect an iOS app. Though out of scope, its useful.

Comment: I was telling him to redo the process because none of the config vars were showing like it should.

Answer (score 0):

you need use https both parse-server and parse-dashboard.
 such as serverURL:"https://localhost:1337/parse" //your parse-server addr.\n
 in parse-dashboard serverURL:"https://110.76.187.79:1337/parse" //your parse-dashboard addr